# How can I restrict access to Accounts in partner community?

Tags: partner-communities

I have a community and have added Partner community users to it. Accounts is set to private and I have one sharing rule that shares accounts with All Internal Users. When I login with a partner user, I can see all accounts. I should only be able to see my own.

User license - Partner Community

Profile - Custom profile with Read/Write/Edit on accounts (No Option for view/Modify all with this license type)

Any idea's what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try the Convert Community Member Access tool ? it's in the Sharing Tools section in Community Settings.

Comment: Have you enabled the external sharing rules?